# Highstock/highcharts - yAxis title width

Tags: charts, highcharts, label

In case I'm using highstock with navigator, yAxis labels are just rendered in chart area, is it somehow possible to take entire space?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the `load` event, by using `css` and `attr` methods you can adjust the title width and position:

```
chart: {
    events: {
        load: function() {
            var title = this.yAxis[0].axisTitle;

            title.attr({
                y: this.chartHeight,
                align: 'left'
            });

            title.css({
                width: this.chartHeight
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mtab0u15/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#css

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#attr

Comment: That's nice, but, it loses the centered property. It gets aligned totally to the left. I kind meant to take usage of entire space so it can center it then.

Comment: Hi @Slaven Tomac, Yes, you are right, here is the corrected version: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rz87yn4s/